# How does changing the CoroutineContext in Flow works? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have set up a `Flow` builder in the `ViewModel` of my project and a `collector` in my `MainActivity`.

My question is what does this mean? `With the flow builder, the producer cannot emit values from a different CoroutineContext. Therefore, don't call emit in a different CoroutineContext by creating new coroutines or by using withContext blocks of code. You can use other flow builders such as callbackFlow in these cases.`

I do not get what they are trying to imply, in my case the `VM` contains both the `Producer` data source and the `Flow Builder`, are they trying to imply both the `Producer` and the `Flow Builder` must be in the same `CoroutineContext`?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var textview:TextView
    lateinit var button:Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)

    var viewModel = viewModel()

    button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    viewModel.setupFlow()

    viewModel.setupFlow()
    setupClicks()
}



private fun setupClicks() {
    button.setOnClickListener {

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            Log.d("CONTEXT", "${coroutineContext.toString()} Main")
            flow
                .catch { exception -> textview.text = "$exception" }
                .collect {
                Log.d("TAG", it.toString())
                textview.text = it.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

companion object{
    lateinit var flow: Flow<Int>

}
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class viewModel: ViewModel() {



fun setupFlow() {
    MainActivity.flow= flow {
        Log.d("TAG", "Start flow")
        (0..10).forEach {
            Log.d("TAG", "Emitting $it")
            Log.d("CONTEXT" , "${currentCoroutineContext().toString()} VM")
            emit(it)

            delay(500)
        }
    }.map {

        it * 10
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
}
```

Comment: I assume it means that the producer can emit items to flow from only one specific coroutine context, therefore you cannot emit values to flow from different threads. However you can observe and collect the flow on the context you want.

Comment: Can you link to the article you're quoting? It might be easier for us to tell what they're talking about if we can see it in context.

Comment: Here's the 
[link](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably referring to this restriction in the flow builder. From [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html):

> `emit` should happen strictly in the dispatchers of the block in order to preserve the flow context.

What this means is that *inside the lambda* you pass to the `flow` builder function, you must not change coroutine contexts to emit anything. Basically, don't use `emit()` inside a `withContext() { }` lambda that's inside a `flow { }` lambda.

Your code above is fine in this regard.

---

By the way, never do this!

```
CoroutineContext(...).launch {
```

You're creating a CoroutineScope without assigning it to any property, so you aren’t managing its lifecycle. This will leak memory and resources, because your coroutine can outlive whatever piece of the app (screen) it's related to. Use `lifecycleScope` to launch your coroutines in an Activity.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but what is the difference between `withContext` and `flowOn`? Both change the context in which the `Flow` is operating on

Comment: `withContext` allows you to change contexts so that emit calls could be done in different contexts. `flowOn` wouldn’t—you would be changing all of the `emit()` calls to the same context, which is safe. Theoretically it would be safe to use withContext if you were careful to use the same context for every emit call, but the compiler isn’t smart enough to detect that so it’s going to throw an exception because they want to make it impossible to violate the rule. I’m not exactly sure of the reason for the rule, but my best guess is that it’s because it would break the `flowOn` operator.

Comment: Actually, if that’s the reason, it wouldn’t be safe to use withContext in any circumstance, because it will always break the flowOn operator.

Comment: Ah so for instance, lets say there are 3 different emits within the flow, I will just label them as emit1, emit2, and emit3. These 3 emits together can operate on any `coroutineContext` I so choose, however, each emit cannot operate on a different `coroutineContext`. For example emit1 cannot be operating on the `IoDispatcher` while emit2 and emit3 operates on the `MainDispatcher`. All emits must be on the same `CoroutineContext`. Is this example correct?

Comment: Yes, but the only way it allows you to choose the context is by using `flowOn`, not by using `withContext`. The documentation for the flow builder outright states that you should use flowOn if you want to choose the context.